# TabItem template based on TabControl.TabStripPlacement

Tags: wpf

The default template for TabItem, as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), assumes that the tab strip is at the top. If we change the `TabStrip.TabStripPlacement` to the right, left or bottom, the margins and border thicknesses don't make sense. How would someone go about changing these values based on the parent `TabControl` `TabStripPlacement`. This is for a style used in application resources not just for a specific instance of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. I found out that there is actually a `TabItem.TabStripPlacement` that can be used on the control template triggers